# BotFramework-Webchat Middleware: set css class names

Tags: typescript, botframework, web-chat

I'd like to add css class names depending on the card type to the corresponding html element.

I already did this by setting the [`AdaptiveCard.customCssSelector`] [1](https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/blob/685b4e0ead10cbf802d7eecd6010cf2d82158a46/source/nodejs/adaptivecards/src/card-elements.ts#L486) attribute.
E.g. you just need to add `builder.card.customCssSelector = "ac-thumbnail";` in [this line](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/a97fbb865982e0bccd3ca1e12d265628ab3441d9/packages/bundle/src/adaptiveCards/Attachment/ThumbnailCardAttachment.js#L34) and the resulting html-block will contain `class="ac-container ac-thumbnail"`.

However, I'd like to be independent of Botframework-Webchat updates and put this logic into a middleware. According to the [BotFramework-Webchat docs](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#web-chat-api-reference) it's possible to add `attachmentMiddleware` to the `renderWebChat` function and manipulate the html elements.
In fact I get activities and attachments, but I'm not able to manipulate html-blocks or add a css selector.

Here's my middleware code:

```
export const cardCssSelector = ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
    if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY') {
        const { activity } = action.payload;
         for (var index in activity.attachments) {       
            const card  = activity.attachments[index].content;
            if(card.tap && card.tap.value){
                card.customCssSelector = 'tap';
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(action);
    return next(action);
};
```

Of course this doesn't work, since the attachments don't have the customCssSelector attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do true custom styling of web chat, then a little hacking is required. Some things to note:

- You need to match to a value that is passed in the card, not in the activity. This allows you to identify the specific card(s) in the html document to be styled. I'm matching on the button text value, for simplicity.
- In Web Chat, with respect to the document, cards are rendered as adaptive cards.
- I recast the `adaptiveCards` [HTMLCollection] to a true array (`cards`) for iterating.
- I add the `card-` classes for mapping the CSS to the card(s).
- Because a basic adaptive card has the same document structure as a converted "hero card" adaptive card, I can count on the buttons being the 3rd child (`children[2]`) for retrieving values. You will need to account for variations in your cards.
- For activities with multiple cards, you will likely need to make adjustments but should be doable following a similar setup to the below.

First, create a store and filter on incoming activities, messages, and then on the `ac-adaptiveCard` class.

```js
const store = window.WebChat.createStore( {}, ( { dispatch } ) => next => async action => {
  if(activity.type === 'message') {
    let aCards = document.body.getElementsByClassName('ac-adaptiveCard');
    let bCards = Object.values( aCards);

    for(let i = 0; i <= bCards.length - 1; i++) {
      if( cards[i].children[2] && cards[i].children[2].innerText && cards[ i ].children[ 2 ].innerText === 'Request Assistance') {
        cards[i].className += ' card-Adaptive'
      }

      if( cards[i].children[2] && cards[i].children[2].innerText && cards[ i ].children[ 2 ].innerText === 'Service details') {
        cards[i].className += ' card-Hero'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I apply styling to the cards by assigned class.

```css
.card-Adaptive {
  background-color: black;
}

.card-Adaptive p {
  color: white;
}

.card-Hero {
  background-color: green;
}
```

I pass `store` as a parameter.

```js
window.ReactDOM.render(
  <ReactWebChat
    directLine={ directLine }
    store={store}
  />,
  document.getElementById( 'webchat' )
);
```

The adaptive card is black and the hero card is green.

[image]

Comment: This helped me. Thank you. Before I mark this as the accepted answer, please remove the code. There're c&p mistakes.

Comment: copy and paste. At least the 2nd part: applying css to the activity is missing a closing div bracket. Also this code refers to an activity. One activity can have several attachments (cards). So this code wraps a div element around all cards and therefore doesn't fit well to my question.

Comment: @ndueck, I updated my answer to better suit your needs. Hope of help!

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but I'm confused.  Since the cards have not been rendered to the DOM yet, how are you adding classes to the elements?